# Why is it correct to say "Honey, I'm home", but "Miel, soy casa" is not?

Tags: english, grammar, spanish

Inspired by the picture below (thanks to [brainlesstaless](http://www.brainlesstales.com/)), when I got home I called to my wife: "Miel, soy casa". After a short pause, she started laughing.

I know in Spanish this sentence makes no sense, but it is correct in English. What leads to the dropping of prepositions? How come this dropping is acceptable in some sentences, and not in others?

[image: Hi Honey, I'm home]

Comment: Welcome to SE Linguistics. "(Hi) Honey, I'm home" is perfectly fine and used frequently. However, I think your question would fit better with SE English Language and Usage, as SE Linguistics is not concerned with language-specific issues on what is grammatical or not.

Comment: What is your question? Your title seems to assume that “Honey, I'm home” is correct, but the body is asking if it actually is.

Comment: @dainichi point taken. Fixed the title.

Comment: Before the edit, your question seemed to be about **null prepositions**. After the edit, it seems to be asking if a particular sentence is grammatical. The former seems on-topic here, and the latter doesn't. What exactly are you going for? Ref. http://linguistics.as.nyu.edu/docs/CP/2345/collins-2007-nyuwpl.pdf

Comment: @prash I would like to keep this as a question about _null prepositions_ (unknown term for me prior to your comment). Only by translating this into Spanish, it made me thinking whether it is correct or not. Also, after your comment, my second question would be if there are _null prepositions_ in Spanish?

Comment: @MarkA: Do you find my modifications acceptable? I tried to make the question better suited for Ling.SE.

Comment: Thank you @prash Yes, they match exactly what I want to find out.

Comment: @prash I really like this paper. It provides the answer and goes deeper into this subject. Would you like to write a short summary and reference the paper in your answer? Otherwise, I can do it on your behalf and mark it as Community Wiki.

Comment: @MarkA: Please go ahead and write the answer. I'm lazy :-). You don't need to mark it Community Wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because *home* is not only a noun: it is also an adverb.  This is not predictable: it just happens to be a fact about English.

Comment: The paper that I mentioned earlier goes into details of why this is a more complex phenomenon.

Comment: @ColinFine, _home is also an adverb_ - that is something new for me and it is a good starting point in answering my question.

Comment: Good, but wouldn't suggest that it's just some unanalyzable quirk of English. Compare the determiner-free *nach Hause* and *zu Hause* in German, suggesting fixed adverbial expressions.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: true. And in Latin, _domus_ is one of the few common (non-proper) nouns which has a distinct locative case.

Comment: @LukeSawczak it is not a quirk of English. In Russian and Hebrew it is also an adverb, in both meanings, be home and go home.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's two different languages and one simply cannot translate a concept word by word from one language to another. Otherwise,  you just sound dumb.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This post would benefit from adding further details. Being a one-line post, it may attract downvotes and criticism. Also please note that we appreciate posts based on scientific research, while this one seems to be solely based on "common sense". Please [edit] it to add further relevant information — preferably with references to credible sources.